# mv command with path wildcard containing random string

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

Im trying to move a file to a path which has a random string that I cannot know in advance `~/.config/foldername/45fhiu84.dev-edition/subfolder/`

I have tried

```
mv ~/Downloads/myfile.txt ~/.config/foldername/*.dev-edition/subfolder/myfile.txt
```

as well as

```
mv ~/Downloads/myfile.txt ~/".config/foldername/"*".dev-edition/subfolder/myfile.txt"
```

Comment: If you don't know where the destination is, neither does mv nor us.

Comment: What happens when you run these two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen Kitt pointed out, the following only works correctly if there's zero or one matching directories. If there's more, the glob will match them all, and you'll end up moving the file and *all but the last directory* into the last directory that matched. Take care.

---

When shell sees an asterisk (or a question mark), it tries to find a path matching the expression. Since you included "myfile.txt" at the end of the path, shell will look for it, and if it doesn't find it, the match will fail.

So in order to move that file into that directory, use:

```
mv ~/Downloads/myfile.txt ~/.config/foldername/*.dev-edition/subfolder/
```

(i.e. just omit the filename.)

If you want to move the file *and* change it name, do it in two steps:

```
mv ~/Downloads/myfile.txt ~/Downloads/newname.txt
mv ~/Downloads/newname.txt ~/.config/foldername/*.dev-edition/subfolder/
```

Comment: And hope there aren't multiple matches for the glob...

Answer (score -1):

Another approach...

```
mv ~/Downloads/myfile.txt $(echo ~/.config/foldername/*.dev-edition/subfolder/)myfile.txt
```

Thanks! =D

Comment: This has no benefit over using the shell glob directly. In the general case, it may instead break in unexpected ways if the path contains spaces or newlines.

Comment: @Kusalananda I find this approach more functional (for other cases included). Something like this...
`echo "test" > ~/.config/foldername/*.dev-edition/subfolder/myfile.txt`
... does not work for me (CentOS 7). Therefore, the contribution is totally valid.

Comment: Try this with a directory that has a space in its name.